# AutoML Vision metadata issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl

I'm trying to use Raspi 3B+ and AutoML Vision to train a model for classification. However, when I try to create a dataset on Google Cloud Platform, it runs into a problem as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api core/grpc helpers.py", line 57, in error remapped callable
return callable (*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/ channel.py", line 826, in call __
return end_unary_response blocking({state, call, False, None)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/ channel.py", line 729, in end unary response blocking
raise InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc. channel. InactiveRpcError: < InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode. INVALID ARGUMENT
details = "List of found errors: 1.Field: parent; Message: Required field is invalid "
debug error string = "{"created":"G1604833054.567218256", "description":"Error received from peer ipv6: [2a00:1450:400a: 801: :200a] :443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file line":1056,"grpc_message":"List of found
errors:\tl.Field: parent; Nessage: Required field is invalid\t","grpc_ status":3}"
>
```

The creating-dataset code is

```py
automl_client = automl.AutoMlClient()
project_location = automl_client.location_path(project_id, region_name)
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

# upload the images to google cloud bucket
upload_image_excel(bucket, bucket_name, dataset_name, status_list, csv_name) 

# Create a new automl dataset programatically
classification_type = 'MULTICLASS' 
dataset_metadata = {'classification_type': classification_type}
dataset_config = {
    'display_name': dataset_name,
    'image_classification_dataset_metadata': dataset_metadata
}

dataset = automl_client.create_dataset(project_location, dataset_config)
dataset_id = dataset.name.split('/')[-1]
dataset_full_id = automl_client.dataset_path(
    project_id, region_name, dataset_id
)

# Read the *.csv file on Google Cloud
remote_csv_path = 'gs://{0}/{1}'.format(bucket_name, csv_name)
input_uris = remote_csv_path.split(',')
input_config = {'gcs_source': {'input_uris': input_uris}}
response = automl_client.import_data(dataset_full_id, input_config)
```

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Which region are you using? Be aware that for this feature, currently project resources must be in the us-central1 region to use this API [1].

The error promting is an INVALID ARGUMENT therefore I do not think the above mentioned is the issue. Looking at the GCP documentation on Creating a dataset [1] I see your code differs from what is done on that sample. The metadata and the configuration is set in a different way. Could you please try to recreate it using the same format as in the sample shared? I believe this should resolve the issue being experienced.

Here you have a code example:

```
from google.cloud import automl

# TODO(developer): Uncomment and set the following variables
# project_id = "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
# display_name = "your_datasets_display_name"

client = automl.AutoMlClient()

# A resource that represents Google Cloud Platform location.
project_location = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/us-central1"
# Specify the classification type
# Types:
# MultiLabel: Multiple labels are allowed for one example.
# MultiClass: At most one label is allowed per example.
# https://cloud.google.com/automl/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.automl.v1#classificationtype
metadata = automl.ImageClassificationDatasetMetadata(
    classification_type=automl.ClassificationType.MULTILABEL
)
dataset = automl.Dataset(
    display_name=display_name,
    image_classification_dataset_metadata=metadata,
)

# Create a dataset with the dataset metadata in the region.
response = client.create_dataset(parent=project_location, dataset=dataset)

created_dataset = response.result()

# Display the dataset information
print("Dataset name: {}".format(created_dataset.name))
print("Dataset id: {}".format(created_dataset.name.split("/")[-1]))
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/create-datasets#automl_vision_classification_create_dataset-python

Comment: Thanks! I solved this problem by directly assigning the Project ID in the code while I used environmental variables in a *.env file. I still don't figure out why using environmental variables is a problem...